# How to use standard-style cursor moving in Terminal of Snow Leopard?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, terminal.app

I want to use command + arrows to move cursor to the beginning and to the end of line, alt + arrows to move it trough words in Terminal (zsh shell).

Are there ways to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to figure this out as well. I found this info here that might be helpful, however I haven't been able to do exactly what you've described. I'll keep on it, but passed this along in case you hadn't seen it.

http://fdiv.net/2007/05/12/keybindings-in-macosx-terminal-app